# MKDistanceFormatter feet to miles

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to force feet into miles. Is there any way to do that?

I'm using MKDistanceFormatterUnitsImperial but it's currently showing feet. I'm guessing it's because until it gets to a certain value it doesn't change.

EDIT: Sorry! I thought I didn't need the code to make me understand, but here it is:

```
     in some method...
     self.distanceValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.formatter stringFromDistance:0]];

    - (MKDistanceFormatter *)formatter
    {
        if (!_formatter) {
            _formatter = [[MKDistanceFormatter alloc] init];
            [self updateFormatterUnits:nil];
        }

        return _formatter;
    }

    - (void)updateFormatterUnits:(NSNotification *)notification {
        self.formatter.units = MKDistanceFormatterUnitsMetric;
        SBSettingValue *distanceUnit = [[SBSettingsManager instance] getValueForSetting:[SBSettingsDefinition distanceUnit]];
        if ([distanceUnit isEqualTo:[SBSettingsDefinition distanceUnitImperial]]) {
            self.formatter.units = MKDistanceFormatterUnitsImperial; // here    
        }
    }
```

PS: The distance keeps getting updated and so, the formatter keeps doing its job. But it starts from zero. Zero feet, not miles.

PS2: I would also like to know from which point passes from feet to miles.

Thank you!

Comment: feet / 5280 = miles

Comment: Please add some code to see what your setup looks like so we can rule out mistakes on the call site

Comment: Update your question with your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The short answer

So you find `MKDistanceFormatter` starts outputting "feet" for small numbers and switches to "miles" only when the distance becomes large enough; I'm afraid this is intentional.

Since different combos of locales and `MKDistanceFormatterUnits` produce different results, there's no way to control the granularity in a general fashion anyway. With my default settings, passing `2` to the formatter produces "2 m", not "2 cm", for example. `CLLocationDistance` (which is just a `Double`) is documented to be measured in meters.

So the short answer is: you're screwed. :)

### The long answer

All of the following depends on your use case and may not be directly applicable.

What you want is use a type or a formatter that combines a numerical value with a specific unit. This also means you have to make sure you're switching from "miles" to "kilometers", depending on the locale. You could totally code this up on your own.

You can also interface with Foundation's new `NSMeasurements` API (requires macOS 10.12 and iOS 10):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmeasurement

Still, you have to convert from the `CLLocationDistance` distance in meters to the proper [`NSUnitLength`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsunitlength?language=objc). The conversion could be done with a set of [`NSUnitConverter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsunitconverterlinear?language=objc) instances.

Something along the lines of this:

```
CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = ...; // Obtain from notification
NSMeasurement *measurementInMeters = [[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:distanceInMeters unit:[NSUnitLength meters]];
NSMeasurement *measurement = [[NSLocale currentLocale] usesMetricSystem]
    ? [measurementInMeters measurementByConvertingToUnit:[NSUnitLength kilometers]]
    : [measurementInMeters measurementByConvertingToUnit:[NSUnitLength miles]];
NSMeasurementFormatter *formatter = [[NSMeasurementFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *distanceText = [formatter stringFromMeasurement: measurement];

self.distanceValueLabel.text = distanceText;
```

Interesting reads for unit conversions:

- `MKUnits` library as a reference for unit conversions: https://github.com/michalkonturek/MKUnits/tree/archive-objc
- Swift code showing formatting extensions and calculations (with hard-coded kilometers-to-miles ratios): https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/blob/master/MapboxCoreNavigation/DistanceFormatter.swift

Answer (score -1):

Updated since I got downvoted. But its hard to tell where to start since there is no code in OP's question.

```
let distance = 2000.0
let formatter = MKDistanceFormatter()
formatter.unitStyle = .full

let distanceString = formatter.string(fromDistance: distance)
```

Comment: While this may turn out to produce the correct numerical result in this case, this approach loses all unit information. The OP didn't say he is providing data in feet himself, only that the result is in feet.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. While not my down vote, keep in mind that if a question is vague, don't answer it. If you want clarification, post a comment below the question and wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: I only saw the ios tag.  I might have overlooked it though

Comment: I know I didn't make myself clear enough. What I meant was that parting from the beginning I want to start in miles. Not with a distance of 2000, but 0, 5 or 10. And get the result in miles.